# Is it possible to set a Django BooleanField default value to True or False depending on a method's output?

Tags: python, django, checkbox, methods

I know how to set the default value, but I'm not sure if it's possible to define it via a method.

@mrdurant: At first it was a scope problem, i had the boolean field before the function I was calling, I placed it after the function but now I get the following error:

"`has_photo` takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

I tried passing arguments but was not able to get it to work.

Note: The `has_photo` function evaluates if a table from another class (`HousingPhotos`) has anything saved in it.

```
class Housing(models.Model):
    h_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    transaction = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publicado')

    def has_photo(self):
        test = Housing(self.pk)
        if test.housingphotos_set.count() == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    has_photo.boolean= True
    show_photo = models.BooleanField(default=has_photo)
```

Comment: have you tried providing a callable function to the default?

Comment: Yep... but I get an error. It say's the function is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a callable in the default value

```
def bar():
    return boolean

your_boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=bar)
```

Or override model's save method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.boolean_field = self.your_method()
    super(ModelClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def you_method(self) 
   return your_boolean #return true or false
```

Comment: I tried the first option but I get a "name 'bar' is not defined" error.

Comment: @alfredordz86 you need to define it previously, edited.

Comment: Bear in mind that default value methods might not have the behavior you expect in migrations, because the underlying SQL expects a constant default value.

Answer (score 0):

Because has_photo is a method, you need to be able to pass self as the first parameter (django assumes a regular function). You can either bring it out of the class to be a regular function, or build a function to call with the appropriate parameter:

```
default=lambda: self.has_photo()
```

It would probably be better to express this as a more verbose function/method call

Comment: I hope this does not fall four of closure rules; we can work around that if necessary.

Comment: Thanks mdurant. I still haven't been able to get it to work. When I use
    default=lambda: self.has_photo()

I get an error telling me "self" is not defined.
I will do some further reading and see if I can eventually do this.

Comment: Actually, it now seems to me that the best and simplest thing to do is not define a default in the BooleanField, but instead set the initial value in a model __init__ method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it since I don't quite understand what that means. I'd leave the BooleanField default as it is, create an __init__ method inside Housing and set the default inside that method?

Comment: No, just remove the default in the field definition (or set to False), and then make the init method.